# Insert into table if two keys do not exist

Tags: mysql, pdo

I have a table that maps itemId(item.id) and tagId(tag.id).

I'm writing a query that needs to insert a new row, but only if BOTH itemId and tagId do not already have an entry. What's the best way to do this?

Here is my current query that doesn't already check for an existing match:

```
// create tag-item maps
$sql = 'INSERT INTO item_tag
      SELECT :itemId AS iid, tag.id AS tid
      FROM tag
      WHERE tag.name=:name';
try{
  $stmt = $db->dbh->prepare($sql);
  for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    $data = array(':itemId' => $itemId, ':name' => $tags[$i]);
    $result = $stmt->execute($data);
    if($result !== false) {
      // Do nothing
    }else {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}catch(PDOException $e) {
 logit($e->getMessage());
 return false;
}
```

Comment: Is there a foreign-key relationship between the tables? That will help determine the best way to check for your condition.

Comment: I didn't set up foreign key constraints initially, although I'm not opposed if it makes this easier

Comment: Actually I just checked and these tables are set up as MyISAM

Comment: OK, then a unique constraint is probably off the table too. But no worries; you can do this with an addition to your `INSERT` query. I'll post an answer shortly, unless someone else posts a workable solution first.

Comment: It turns out MyISAM does support UNIQUE constraints, so that's one of the options I presented below. If you're writing a high-traffic "can't fail" app then UNIQUE is safest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `UNIQUE` constraint would be the ideal solution, and according to the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/myisam-storage-engine.html) the MyISAM engine supports them.

```
ALTER TABLE item_tag ADD CONSTRAINT item_tag_iid_tid_uq UNIQUE (iid, tid);
```

Then if your `INSERT` tries to add a duplicate (`iid`, `tid`) pair it will throw and you can handle it in your `catch` code.

If you don't want to do the `UNIQUE` constraint, you could instead add an "existence" check to your `INSERT` query:

```
INSERT INTO item_tag
  SELECT :itemId AS iid, tag.id AS tid
  FROM tag
  WHERE tag.name=:name' AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM item_tag WHERE iid=:itemId AND tid=tag.id)
```

I tested this using my own differently-named tables, so hopefully I "translated" it correctly to your table/column names.

Comment: I set up the constraint. But now when an existing match happens, $result is coming in as false. So I'm not sure how I'd go about catching this exception.

Comment: Hmm, I thought it would throw but that was a guess. A wrong guess as it turns out: I just looked up the [PDO execute](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) and it states that it will return `FALSE` on failure. That's OK though because you can check the MySQL error number once you know there's a failure, and from that you can determine if it failed due to a unique constraint violation. I'll update the answer in a minute.

Comment: Figured it out. I can get the error from $stmt->errorInfo() after checking for the query fail. It's not thrown apparently

Comment: Excellent, I'm glad it worked out! I'll leave the answer as-is then, rather than add more conjecture (I'm not near my PHP machine today) :)